# Testlink upgrade got issue "You need to proceed with Manual upgrade of your DB scheme to DB 1.9.15"

Tags: mysql, mariadb, testlink

I'm using xampp to handle php, mysql and apahce. The older version xampp is using the MySQL, and the latest version is using the MariaDB. I'm upgrade xampp and testlink as below:

1. In older version xampp (v5.6.8), `# mysqldump -u root -p testlink > ~/backup.sql`
2. Stop the lampp service and backup order version lampp: `# mv /opt/lampp /opt/lampp.bak`
3. Install new version [lampp-linux v5.6.24-1.run](https://downloadsapachefriends.global.ssl.fastly.net/xampp-files/5.6.24/xampp-linux-x64-5.6.24-1-installer.run?from_af=true)
4. Download and install the latest verion testlink (v1.9.15) to `/opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink`
5. Update couple of configuration files, so http://localhost/phpmyadmin can be visited
6. http://localhost/testlink/install/default.php to start a **new install**, after that, http://localhost/testlink can be visit and also login by admin.
7. restore the mysql data which has been dumpped in step 1： `# mysql -u root -p testlink < ~/backup.sql`

Then http://localhost/testlink/login.php shows:

> You need to proceed with Manual upgrade of your DB scheme to DB 1.9.15
>
> - Read README file!

I've also checked the http://localhost/testlink/README:

> - Upgrade from 1.9.14 to 1.9.15 WARNING: if you are using a table prefix replace /*prefix*/ with your prefix
>
> a) Execute
> install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.15/<your_db>/DB.1.9.15/step1/db_schema_update.sql
>
> b) Execute (IF EXISTS)
> install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.15/<your_db>/DB.1.9.15/stepZ/z_final_step.sql

But I don't know how to **execute** a sql script in commandline.

====

- I'm tried to use `# mysql_update -u root -p` to update the database,
  but looks like nothing changed.
- I've also import dump sql file by force way: `# mysql -u root -p --force testlink < ~/backup.sql`, but nothing changes also.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally I understand how to update the db schame. Here is the way:

```
# mysql -u root -p
MariaDB [(none)]> use testlink;
MariaDB [testlink]> source /opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.14/mysql/DB.1.9.14/step1/db_schema_update.sql
MariaDB [testlink]> source /opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.14/mysql/DB.1.9.14/stepZ/z_final_step.sql
MariaDB [testlink]> source /opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.15/mysql/DB.1.9.15/step1/db_schema_update.sql
MariaDB [testlink]> source /opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.15/mysql/DB.1.9.15/stepZ/z_final_step.sql
```

**DONE!**

The truth is, want to upgrade a lower version testlink to a higher version, then it should be execute the `/opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/**/step1/db_schema_update.sql` and `/opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/**/stepZ/db_schema_update.sql` step by step. For example, if want to upgrade testlink from `1.9.10` to `1.9.15`, then the db schema should be upgrade as below:

1. 1.9.10 -> 1.9.11
2. 1.9.11 -> 1.9.12
3. 1.9.12 -> 1.9.13
4. 1.9.13 -> 1.9.14
5. 1.9.14 -> 1.9.15

Comment: I am trying to upgrade 1.9.15-1 to 1.9.16-6. I'm not able to run Upgrade db schema.can you please help how to execute these queries exactly.

Answer (score 0):

- Install dependencies:

  1. mysql 5.6 (Note that testlink 1.9.16 database requires mysql 5.6 as 
     minimum version)
  2. php 5.6
  3. apache2
- Download testlink latest version tar package.
- backup production db.
- backup production configuration files.
- dump database to a new database, say tl1916
- Upgrade database:

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.8/mysql/DB.1.9.8/step1/db_schema_update.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.8/mysql/DB.1.9.8/stepZ/z_final_step.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.9/mysql/DB.1.9.9/step1/db_schema_update.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.9/mysql/DB.1.9.9/stepZ/z_final_step.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.10/mysql/DB.1.9.10/step1/db_data_update.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.11/mysql/DB.1.9.11/step1/db_schema_update.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.11/mysql/DB.1.9.11/stepZ/z_final_step.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.12/mysql/DB.1.9.12/step1/db_schema_update.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.12/mysql/DB.1.9.12/stepZ/z_final_step.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.13/mysql/DB.1.9.13/step1/db_schema_update.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.13/mysql/DB.1.9.13/stepZ/z_final_step.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.14/mysql/DB.1.9.14/step1/db_schema_update.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.14/mysql/DB.1.9.14/stepZ/z_final_step.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.15/mysql/DB.1.9.15/step1/db_schema_update.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.15/mysql/DB.1.9.15/stepZ/z_final_step.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.16/mysql/DB.1.9.16/step1/db_schema_update.sql

  source /var/www/html/testlink/install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.16/mysql/DB.1.9.16/stepZ/z_final_step.sql

**Explanation of above steps:**
- Upgrade from 1.9.7 to 1.9.8
WARNING: if you are using a table prefix replace /*prefix*/ with your prefix
a) Execute install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.8//DB.1.9.8/step1/db_schema_update.sql
b) Execute install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.8//DB.1.9.8/stepZ/z_final_step.sql

- Upgrade from 1.9.8 to 1.9.9
  WARNING: if you are using a table prefix replace /*prefix*/ with your prefix
  a) Execute install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.9//DB.1.9.9/step1/db_schema_update.sql
  b) Execute install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.9//DB.1.9.9/stepZ/z_final_step.sql
- Upgrade from 1.9.9 to 1.9.10
  WARNING: if you are using a table prefix replace /*prefix*/ with your prefix
  a) Execute install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.10//DB.1.9.10/step1/db_data_update.sql
- Upgrade from 1.9.10 to 1.9.11
  WARNING: if you are using a table prefix replace /*prefix*/ with your prefix
  a) Execute install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.11//DB.1.9.11/step1/db_schema_update.sql
  b) Execute install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.11//DB.1.9.11/stepZ/z_final_step.sql
- Upgrade from 1.9.11 to 1.9.12
  WARNING: if you are using a table prefix replace /*prefix*/ with your prefix
  a) Execute install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.12//DB.1.9.12/step1/db_schema_update.sql
  b) Execute install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.12//DB.1.9.12/stepZ/z_final_step.sql
- Upgrade from 1.9.12 to 1.9.13
  WARNING: if you are using a table prefix replace /*prefix*/ with your prefix
  a) Execute install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.13//DB.1.9.13/step1/db_schema_update.sql
  b) Execute install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.13//DB.1.9.13/stepZ/z_final_step.sql
- Upgrade from 1.9.13 to 1.9.14
  WARNING: if you are using a table prefix replace /*prefix*/ with your prefix
  a) Execute install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.14//DB.1.9.14/step1/db_schema_update.sql
  b) Execute install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.14//DB.1.9.14/stepZ/z_final_step.sql
- Upgrade from 1.9.14 to 1.9.15
  WARNING: if you are using a table prefix replace /*prefix*/ with your prefix

a) Execute install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.15//DB.1.9.15/step1/db_schema_update.sql

b) Execute (IF EXISTS) install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.15//DB.1.9.15/stepZ/z_final_step.sql

- Upgrade from 1.9.15 to 1.9.16
  WARNING: if you are using a table prefix replace /*prefix*/ with your prefix

a) Execute install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.16//DB.1.9.16/step1/db_schema_update.sql

b) Execute (IF EXISTS) install/sql/alter_tables/1.9.16//DB.1.9.16/stepZ/z_final_step.sql

Configure web server.
Restore config files:
config.inc.php needs to be restored via manual merge. DO NOT COPY THIS FILE FROM OLD VERSION.
config_db.inc.php: configure per db setting.
custom_config.inc.php: Copy from production instance.